# PHP Heroku - extra index.php fiule causing routing issue

Tags: php, heroku

I have just finished a Udemy course, and everything works fine on localhost.

To deploy on Heroku, I added an extra index.php file at the root folder because Heroku couldn't 'see' the index.php file within the public folder. So I simply added `include 'public/index.php';` to the new index.php file. So far, the site now loads.

However, the links in the navbar no longer work. You'll see in the code below for the navbar, I used variable URLROOT in my config file (this works in localhost) but since I added the index.php, things have changed, and I get a 500 Internal Server Error when clicking the links.

```
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
      <!-- home and about page links on left of navbar  -->
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/pages/about">About</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <!-- register and login links on right of navbar  -->
      <!-- Contains php if to show/hide navbar options  -->
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <?php if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) : ?>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Welcome, <?php echo $_SESSION['user_name']; ?></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/users/logout">Logout</a>
          </li>
        <?php else : ?>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/users/register">Register</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/users/login">Login</a>
          </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

I have tried adding `/app` to the front of the file paths after the URLROOT, as this is the folder where everything is stored. But still I get the error.

I also tried as a punt adding the /app to the end of the URLROOT variable in the config file but that breaks things completely.

The config file...

```
<?php
// App root 
define('APPROOT', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));

// URL Root
define('URLROOT', 'http://localhost/php-share-posts');
//Site name
```

As a curveball, there is an htaccess file that may play a part in this, stopping the reading of a path inside the app folder? This is a guess, likely wrong. HTAccess file...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
  RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Here is the folder layout... The root folder contains 4 things...

```
App folder (with main code)
Public folder (with index.php, css etc)
.htaccess file
.index.php (including the public inex.php file)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using rewrite or includes to do this.

You can tell Apache or nginx to point to the public folder in your Procfile.

For Apache, `web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/` does the trick. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-php-settings#setting-the-document-root for more details.

Comment: I have changed my code to have the procfile.txt as you have suggested and is detailed on Heroku.com, thank you

Comment: However, the problem with the routing still persists - 500 Internal Server Error . The links don't work. Any ideas?

Comment: It's not `procfile.txt`, it's `Procfile`. It won't do anything if you name it wrong. As for the 500 error, you need to give us the error message from the logs; it'll include details on what the error was caused by.

Comment: Yes, I didn't type it right here, but in my code it is okay. 
Anyway, I found the problem. I had a redirect in an htaccess file with a full file path which needed trimming down to just the public folder. Thanks for your help, it's something I didn't know, so thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was an htaccess file that had a redirect to a full file path that I was using in the developoment phase. When uploaded to Heroku, this needed to be just directed to the public folder. Problem solved.